# App stopped working error whenever device is rebooted and alarms are to be reset

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app which will include an alarm. Whenever the device is rebooted, I want to reset the alarms again. In order to do so I am using a broadcast receiver to receive the boot completed action and then reset the alarm. However when I run the application and then reboot the device, I get an error message saying my app has stopped working.

Can anyone tell me why this occurs? Thanks

**Broadcast Receiver code:**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,50);

      if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
      {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm has been reset for " + cal.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // Set the alarm here.
         Intent resetAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234, resetAlarm, 0);
         AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
      }
   }
}
```

**Android manifest file:**

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you checked logcat for any error messages?

Comment: For some reason logcat hasn't been working all day, so I have that problem too. Trying to find a solution to that now.